# Jinja2 Strange template behaviour

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am using bootstrap CSS and trying to add content in two side-by-side divs. The problem is that I'm getting all of the content put into one div, interleaved.

```html
{% if pred_ext != None %}
<div class="col-md-3">
    <h3>Both Teams to Score</h3>
    <h3>{{ pred_ext["BTTS"] }}</h3>
    <h3>{{ pred_ext["noBTTS"] }}</h3>
</div>
{% endif %}

{% if pred_ext != None %}
<div class="col-md-9">
    <h3>Both Over 2.5</h3>
    <h3>{{ pred_ext["over25"] }}</h3>
    <h3>{{ pred_ext["under25"] }}</h3>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

All of the content ends up in the `col-md-9` div. It looks like:

```
Both Teams to Score
Both Over 2.5
1.9
2.0
1.2
3.8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd not closed a `<table>` tag. When I fixed that it behaved properly.